# unable to bar plot the data for all the columns

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plotting

I am trying to plot the data in a loop, I am using the below code to build the plot. but Its running for all the loop, I can see the column name is getting printed for all th but its building the plot for only the last one. is there anything I have add extra to generate the plot for individual iteration?

> ```
> for (index, colname) in enumerate(df):
>     print(colname)
>     counts = df[colname].value_counts(dropna=False)
>     counts.plot.bar(title=colname, grid=True)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing is that by calling the drawing function, you are constantly redrawing the same figure.
Try to create a figure every time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for (index, colname) in enumerate(df):
    print(colname)
    plt.figure()
    counts = df[colname].value_counts(dropna=False)
    counts.plot.bar(title=colname, grid=True)
```

You can also divide one drawing into many parts and draw several graphs at a time using matplotlib subplots.
[matplotlib subplots doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks for the subplot tip.